# After Effects can't create proportional shapes

Tags: shapes, adobe-after-effects

I wanted to create a square shape so I hold shift and left mouse button to draw it, and it seems like I have a very strange bug. The shape on the screenshot is the result of shift+lmb - clearly not a square. So I tried to set the size manualy but, as it shows on the screenshot, apparently AE thinks this shape is 272x272 pixels. I tried to create new compositions, re-open program and create comps with locked aspect ratio to 1:1 but nothing worked.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check your screen resolution, or your display card, there's nothing wrong in your proportional square drawing as you're showing the values.

Hope that answers the question

Answer (score 0):

Here's your Somthing you can relate to :

https://community.adobe.com/t5/after-effects-discussions/proportional-scaling-masks-in-after-effects-is-not-working-for-me/td-p/11386995

Comment: Welcome to Graphic Design! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/112512)